# String to ZonedDateTime is changing format

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

```
String ip="2011-05-01T06:47:35.422-05:00";
ZonedDateTime mzt = ZonedDateTime.parse(ip).toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(mzt);

System.out.println("-----");

String ip2="2011-05-01T00:00:00.000-05:00";
ZonedDateTime mzt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(ip2).toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(mzt2);
```

**Output:**

```
2011-05-01T11:47:35.422Z
-----
2011-05-01T05:00Z
```

Why is the date format getting changed in case 2? I am getting SQLServer Database error due to this.

Comment: By the way, you are using the wrong class for your inputs and your manipulations. `OffsetDateTime` is appropriate here, whereas `ZonedDateTime` is for when you have a time zone, `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal` or `Africa/Tunis`. And when you want UTC, just stick with `Instant`.

Comment: Please read [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) before posting a Question on such a simple method call.

Answer (score 7):

This is what [toString from documentation said](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--)

> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
>   the time **where the omitted parts are implied to be zero**.

To solve this problem, you need another formatter :

```
String result = mzt2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"));
```

Output

```
2011-05-01T11:47:35.422Z
2011-05-01T05:00:00:000Z
```

Comment: Your answer gets the correct result. But i want the ZonedDateTime Object

Comment: @SujanDavangereSunil You already have the `ZonedDateTime Object` but you can't get the expected result because when you try to print this Object It will call the `toString` method so this method will return that result you shared It will ommit the last zeros from the `ZonedDateTime` so can you please share more information about your problem so we can help you to solve it?

Comment: I have printed in System.out here just to see the output. All i want is the ZonedDateTimeObject in that format which case 1 is.

Comment: A `ZonedDateTime` cannot have a format. It only has a `toString` method, and you cannot change how that method works. If you want a specific format, you need to have that format in a `String` (not in a `ZonedDateTime`). This is also a sound distinction: Use a `ZonedDateTime` for your model and a `String` for your presentation. Also, why do you want that specific format when ISO 8601 allows for the freedom that `toString` takes?

Comment: @SujanDavangereSunil read the comment of Ole V.V. please, it answer your previous question

Comment: I want the value of mzt2 to be 2011-05-01T05:00:00:000Z. Using System.out.print will make use of formatter to print this. In my case i am making a entry into Database which needs the ZonedDateTime Object value to be 2011-05-01T05:00:00:000Z

Comment: @SujanDavangereSunil You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454) here. You think your problem is that `toString()` is generating the wrong string for insert into database, when your real problem is that you're calling `toString()` at all. Don't convert the date value to a string for insert into database, insert the date value itself. If your JDBC driver cannot handle the new Java Time objects, convert to `Timestamp` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement YCF_L's answer:

Using a quoted letter in the pattern, like it was done with the Z (it's inside quotes: `'Z'`) is wrong. This will treat Z as a literal and ignore the object's offset.

**For this particular case**, it works, but the "Z" in the end means that the date is in UTC, and you can't hardcode it as a literal. Putting it inside quotes will always print "Z" no matter what's the offset, giving wrong results.

Example:

```
// wrong: it uses Z inside quotes
DateTimeFormatter wrong = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'");

// correct: it uses the offset pattern (X)
DateTimeFormatter correct = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXX");

// print a date/time not in UTC
String ip2 = "2011-05-01T00:00:00.000-05:00";
ZonedDateTime mzt = ZonedDateTime.parse(ip2);

System.out.println(mzt.format(wrong)); // 2011-05-01T00:00:00:000Z
System.out.println(mzt.format(correct)); // 2011-05-01T00:00:00:000-05:00
```

Note that the wrong formatter prints Z, which is wrong, because the offset of `mzt` is `-05:00`.

The wrong formatter works **for your case** because you're using UTC:

```
// convert to UTC
ZonedDateTime mzt2 = mzt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(mzt2.format(wrong)); // 2011-05-01T05:00:00:000Z
System.out.println(mzt2.format(correct)); // 2011-05-01T05:00:00:000Z
```

In this case, both formatters prints the correct result, but **that's a coincidence**, because `mzt2` is in UTC (so the offset is "Z"). But for any offset different than UTC, only the correct formatter will work.

Also note that I used `withZoneSameInstant`, that has the same result as using `.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.