# Can’t rid of 'T' in LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, date

Here is the problem:

```
    @GetMapping("/main/search")
    public String search (@RequestParam String departure,
                          @RequestParam String arrival,
                          @RequestParam String departureTime,
                          Model model) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        departureTime+=" 00:00:00"; 
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime, formatter);

        List<BusFlight> busflights = busFlightService.search(departure, arrival, date);
```

Format comes like **2015-10-23T03:34:40**

When I try to solve problem this way:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        departureTime+=" 00:00:00";  
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime, formatter);
        String currentDate = date.format(formatter);

        List<BusFlight> busflights = busFlightService.search(departure, arrival, currentDate);
```

I get problem in another place. Java requires to change type `LocalDateTime` to String type in my service calass:

```
public List<BusFlight> search(String departure, String arrival, **LocalDateTime** departureTime)* 
{
    *LocalDateTime departureTimeTho = departureTime.**plusDays(1)**;*
```

And if I change `LocalDateTime` to `String`, a can't use method **plusDays(1)**  :(((

And I also tried this way:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        departureTime+="T00:00:00";
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime, formatter);
```

format comes the same with charater 'T'  **2018-09-13T05:42:28**

This way also not working for me:

```
 String localTime = "2018-09-13 00:00:00";
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
       LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(localTime, formatter);
     String replace = date.toString().replace("T", " ");
```

becuse a cann't change type to String

And this way not working becouse of exception: ***Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds***

```
String localdatetime = "2011-05-01";
        localdatetime+="T00:00:00";
        DateTimeFormatter date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddXXX:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        LocalDateTime mzt = LocalDateTime.parse(localdatetime);
        System.out.println(mzt.format(date));
```

Please help! How can I solve the problem?

**Please CHECK my SCREENSHOTS for undestanding problem**

[**MY CONTROLLER**](http://www.picshare.ru/view/9016768/)

[**MY SERVICE**](http://www.picshare.ru/view/9016769/)

[**MY REPOSITORY**](http://www.picshare.ru/view/9016770/)

[**MY DATAPICKER FORMAT**](http://www.picshare.ru/view/9016771/)

[**MY VIEW**](http://www.picshare.ru/view/9016765/)

Comment: I didn’t understand your exact problem. As far as possible pass `LocalDateTime` or another date-time type around rather than strings. You are correct that a `DateTimeFormatter` can convert between strings without `T` and `LocalDateTime` (for parsing a string *with* a `T` in it just use the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse` and no formatter).

Comment: There is no `T` in a `LocalDateTime`. It’s `toString` method produces a string with a `T` in it, and there is no way you can avoid that. Also why would you? For presenting the `LocalDateTime` to a user you should of course format it using a `DateTimeFormatter`, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatSyle.MEDIUM)`.

Comment: I need LocalDateTime to use method plusDays(1) i can't parse to anther DateTime  Or I Can ?

Comment: Your question already shows how to parse into a `LocalDateTime` and use `plusDays`. I am sorry, I cannot see that you have any issue.

Comment: Possibly related: [String to ZonedDateTime is changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format)

Comment: Ole V.V. sorry didn't get it. Can give me some more info?

Comment: The linked question is about wanting a `ZonedDateTime` to look in a specific way (with seconds and fraction of second). If I understood your question correctly, you are asking to have a `LocalDateTime` look in a specific way (without `T`). In that way I thought the questions were similar. If they aren’t to you, just ignore my comment.

Comment: I am downvoting because you still don’t seem to have made any attempt to explain what harm you think that `T` does. If you will explain that, I’m sure we’ll understand your situation better and that we can suggest something.

Comment: The offset "X" is present in ZonedDateTime not in LocalDatetime :(

Comment: and i get exception : Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds

Answer (score 4):

There is no `T` in a `LocalDateTime`. Date-time objects do not have a “format”.

On the other hand its `toString` method invariably produces a string with a `T` in it, per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for text representing date-time values. You cannot change the `toString` method nor its behaviour.

The way to avoid getting the `T` is avoiding calling the `toString` method directly or indirectly. This also means: don’t print the `LocalDateTime` object and don’t use it in string concatenations.

The facts mentioned so far do no harm in the code you have posted, so I suggest you learn to live it.

EDIT: If I read the first two screen shots linked to from your comments correctly, they show that your debugger shows your `LocalDateTime` object with a `T` in it. Your debugger too calls `LocalDateTime.toString`. There’s no way I could keep my debugger from doing that and hence showing the `T`, so I don’t expect there is in yours either. You are fighting the wrong problem. I recommend you stop doing that and learn to live with it.

You are correct that you should pass a `LocalDateTime` as the last argument to `busFlightService.search` (if departure and arrival are also dates and/or times, I suggest you use an appropriate date/time type for them too rather than strings). So that you can use `plusDays` inside the method (and similar advantages).

If at some point you need to present the `LocalDateTime` to a user, you are correct that the user does not want to see the `T`. You can generate text in any format by using a `DateTimeFormatter`. That class can even localize the text being generated to represent your `LocalDateTime` object.

```
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-23T03:34:40");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));
    System.out.println(dt.format(formatter));
```

Output:

> 23 окт. 2015 г., 3:34:40

Now there’s no `T` (except the `т` in `окт.`). Internally in your program always use `LocalDateTime` or another appropriate date-time class. Only for presentation use a string.

This separation is widely used and recommended in computing: the one between your model and business logic on one side and user interface and presentation on the other.

PS: As an aside, if you receive the departure time as a string like `2015-10-23` (yyyy-MM-dd), you don’t need to modify the string in order to convert it to `LocalDateTime`. Either use `LocalDate` instead or convert like this:

```
    String departureTime = "2015-10-23";
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDate.parse(departureTime).atStartOfDay();
```

Comment: public String search (@RequestParam String departure,
@RequestParam String arrival,
@RequestParam String departureTime,
   Model model) {
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime + "T00:00:00");
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                                                    .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));

            System.out.println(date.format(formatter));

            List<BusFlight> busflights = busFlightService.search(departure, arrival, date);          `

Comment: **date inde buger 2015-10-23T03:34:40**

Comment: “*date inde buger 2015-10-23T03:34:40*” Yes, there’s no way to avoid that. See my edit. I cannot read the code in your comment since comments don’t allow code formatting and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that `T` character which you passed as an argument.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd**'T'**HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

For more help you can take help from this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: **I still din't get a clean answer** _I didn't undestand it ;(((_

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have solved your problem in your own way.

I suggest:

You can take another parameter when you request the "search" method. The another parameter is `DateTimeFormatter formatter`, so that you can use your way:

```
LocalDateTime departureTimeTho = departureTime.plusDays(1);
String date = departureTimeTho.format(formatter)
```

Comment: No a can't change type  to String becase in my mySql Datebase type DATETIME