# Format ZonedDateTime and return ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime-format, zoneddatetime

I have below ZonedDateTime object:

```
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]");
```

Need to return another ZonedDateTime object with value: 06-Aug-2021 19:01:32 IST

I can format it like below:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zz");
 String s = z1.withZoneSameInstant(ZonedDateTime.now().getZone()).format(df);
```

but I need to return ZonedDateTime not String.
How do I now convert it back to ZonedDateTime. If I parse again timezone shifts or time value is changed.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're actually trying to do? Ignore the string representation: you've got one `ZonedDateTime` value, and you want another one... but what should the difference between the two be? Why are you formatting at all? It's really unclear to me at the moment.

Comment: Isn't `"Asia/Kolkata"` resp. `"Asia/Calcutta"` the time zone considered `"IST"`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have one ZonedDateTime obj with value "2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]" and I need to write a method to convert it to another ZonedDateTime  with new formatting 06-Aug-2021 19:01:32 IST so that the consuming method can print it this new ZonedDateTime object as it is.

Comment: Could you please explain which *IST* you mean? Is it *Indian Standard Time* or something else? Trying to resolve *IST* via `ZoneId.of("IST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)` gets you exactly the zone you want to convert **from**!

Comment: @deHaar yes same IST - Indian Standard Time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String to ZonedDateTime is changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format)

Comment: @deHaar Not *the* time zone as in the only one. Irish Summer Time and Israel Standard Time are also abbreviated IST, and there are still more.

Comment: "I need to write a method to convert it to another ZonedDateTime with new formatting" - a ZonedDateTime doesn't have a format. What you're asking is a bit like saying "I've got an integer with a value of 16, and I want to convert it to a hex integer". You need to differentiate between the inherent value you're working with, and a formatted representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `ZonedDateTime` holds no format, no text

> but I need to return ZonedDateTime not String.

**Short answer:** It is not possible.

**Explanation:**

The standard Date-Time classes do not have any attribute to hold the formatting information. Even if some library or custom class promises to do so, it is breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). A Date-Time object is supposed to store the information about Date, Time, Timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. The only way to represent a Date-Time object in the desired format is by formatting it into a **`String`** using a Date-Time parsing/formatting type:

- ***For the modern Date-Time API***: `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`
- ***For the legacy Date-Time API***: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

### The 3-letter abbreviation for the timezone ID:

The problem with the 3-letter abbreviation e.g. `IST` is that it can specify many timezones; therefore, you need to change it to the desired timezone ID as per the naming convention, *Region/City*. Given below is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
> IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their
> use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for
> multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
> Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
> then only recognize one of them.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]");
        DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String s = z1.format(df);
        System.out.println(s);

        // Getting the original ZonedDateTime from the string
        s = s.replace("IST", "Asia/Calcutta");
        ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, df);
        System.out.println(z2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
06-Aug-2021 19:01:32 IST
2021-08-06T19:01:32+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NbdlFg)

Comment: The OP is trying to get a second `ZonedDateTime`, *not* a string.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry, I can understand your frustration.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to just use overloaded version [`parse(CharSequence t, DateTimeFormatter f`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)), as:

```java
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime
        .parse("2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Or, if you instist you want to have two distinct objects:

```java
String zdt = "2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]";

ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(zdt);
ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(zdt, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: Results into error: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: @nanosoft that's because I've just copied your pattern.. which appears to be invalid. You have a year, in the object.. and you have a `dd` in the formatter. Could you specify how **exactly** you wish to format the object?

Comment: I have one ZonedDateTime obj with value "2021-08-06T19:01:32.632+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]" and I need to write a method to convert it to another ZonedDateTime with new formatting 06-Aug-2021 19:01:32 IST so that the consuming method can print it this new ZonedDateTime object as it is.

Comment: @nanosoft oh... that completely changes your question and answers Jon's confusion.. update your question appropriately. You want to convert from one format to another.