# Remove time zone part from - ZonedDateTime : JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, timezone, java-time, zoneddatetime

I am converting milliseconds into ZonedDateTime

```
Long lEpochMilliSeconds = 1668415926445;
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(lEpochMilliSeconds),ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

It gives output:

```
2022-10-28T12:59:34.939Z[UTC]
```

I don't want the time zone "[UTC]" part in my output.
I need my out to be like this in ZonedDateTime format:

```
2022-10-28T12:59:34.939Z
```

I need the **forma**t in **ZonedDateTime** only **not string**, as I will be  returning the value & use it somewhere else

Comment: Use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime`. It’s more appropriate and gives you the result you want. `OffsetDateTime` goes the same way as the code you have. `Instant` is simpler: `System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1668415926445L));` prints `2022-11-14T08:52:06.445Z`.

Comment: Similar: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714896/format-zoneddatetime-and-return-zoneddatetime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945507/zoneddatetime-ofinstant-not-showing-seconds).

Comment: Removing the zone from a `ZonedDateTime`, that’s a contradiction in terms. Like removing the `i` from an `int`. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

> I need the format in `ZonedDateTime` only not string

This is like saying "I need an `int` that knows it's in hex rather than decimal". There's just no such concept.

If you need to format the value in a particular way, you should apply that format *where you do the formatting*.

It's possible that what you should actually do is return an `Instant` instead of a `ZonedDateTime`. That will format the way you want by default, although it's still not "part of the object" - just the default format for all instants.

It's important to understand the difference between "the value being represented" (and the type you're using to represent that value) and "a string representation of that value". You should try use the semantically-appropriate type for what you're trying to represent (e.g. `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` etc) for as much of the time as possible, only converting to and from string representations at system boundaries. Those system boundaries need to be aware of the expected textual representation, and perform the appropriate conversion, rather than expecting a particular string representation to travel with the value itself through the system.

Answer (score 1):

It is giving me the desired output when I gave ZoneOffset as an argument instead of ZoneId.

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(lEpochMilliSeconds), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: This doesn't address your fundamental point of misunderstanding though: that the format isn't part of the value. This *happens* to work because of the way `ZoneOffset.UTC` is formatted by default, but you should change the way you *think* about these values and how you convert them to strings.